# Android App crashed when i try to open it

Tags: java, android

I am building a Calendar app which will store events through sqlite database when i finished building it is always  crashing for some reason and i don't know where the errors at.

This is my logcat

```
              --------- beginning of crash
     E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar, PID: 25587
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar/com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CustomCalendarActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2600)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412)
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2229)
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CustomCalendarActivity.onCreate(CustomCalendarActivity.java:11)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6347)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412) 
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2229) 
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CustomCalendarActivity.onCreate(CustomCalendarActivity.java:11) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6347) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
               Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619)
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412) 
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2229) 
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CustomCalendarActivity.onCreate(CustomCalendarActivity.java:11) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6347) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679) 
               Caused by: com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper$SQLiteAssetException: Missing databases/events file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.openAsset(Native Method)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:325)
                  at android.content.res.AssetManager.open(AssetManager.java:299)
                  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.copyDatabaseFromAssets(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:436)
                  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.createOrOpenDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:400)
                  at com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset.SQLiteAssetHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteAssetHelper.java:176)
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.database.DatabaseObject.<init>(DatabaseObject.java:10)
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.database.DatabaseQuery.<init>(DatabaseQuery.java:0)
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView.setUpCalendarAdapter(CalendarCustomView.java:89)
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView.<init>(CalendarCustomView.java:43)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:619) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:764) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
                  at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:412) 
                  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2229) 
                  at com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CustomCalendarActivity.onCreate(CustomCalendarActivity.java:11) 
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6347) 
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2547) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2682) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1496) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5777) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

This is my layout

### activity_custom_calendar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_custom_calendar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CustomCalendarActivity">
<com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView
    android:id="@+id/custom_calendar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar.CalendarCustomView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can you help me where the errors at? I am new to android thanks

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is written

> Missing databases/events file (or .zip, .gz archive) in assets, or target folder not writable

Ensure you have an sqlite database included if you are referencing it

Comment: This is my code in CustomCalendarActivity    'package com.mobile.aaron.aaroncalendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
public class CustomCalendarActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = CustomCalendarActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_custom_calendar);
        CalendarCustomView mView = (CalendarCustomView)findViewById(R.id.custom_calendar);
    }
}'

Comment: The problem is you're trying to populate that calendar view from a database somewhere that you havent registered